# How to Resume Scrapy Spider from the Last Known State if it Quits Due to Unexpected Reasons?

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler, screen-scraping

I am using Scrapy to scrape some big websites. Sometimes, my Scrapy spider quits due to unexpected reasons, and when I start it again, it runs from the start. This causes incomplete scraping of big sites. I have tried using a database connection to save the status of each category as it is in progress or completed, but it does not work because all components in Scrapy work in parallel.

How can I start my Scrapy spider from the position where it left off? I have heard about the built-in feature in Scrapy called 'Resuming Crawls,' but I don't know how to implement it. Also, is there any way to limit the number of concurrent requests that my spider makes to improve its stability?

Comment: You can use [CONCURRENT_REQUESTS](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#concurrent-requests). This question is actually multiple questions. Read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and edit your question.